# Notify/Listen: AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0

Tags: postgresql

I am using [Notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-notify.html) and [Listen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-listen.html) on PostgreSQL 9.4 . It's strange to me when getting log as below:

```
Apr 24 23:53:05 server postgres[6134]: [8-1] user=,db= LOG:  duration: 2450.632 ms  execute <unnamed>: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mapping_objects
Apr 25 00:00:10 server postgres[6646]: [8-1] user=,db= LOG:  process 6646 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 1000.076 ms
Apr 25 00:00:10 server postgres[6646]: [8-2] user=,db= DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 6134. Wait queue: 6875, 6646, 6132, 5642, 5890, 7856, 7863.
```

On the other hand, I could not find the ***AccessExclusiveLock*** *mode* in the [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-locks.html) at the same time.

Does anyone know why it happen ?

As [Tom Lane's message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3598.1363354686%40sss.pgh.pa.us), It can be a lock on Notify queue.

Comment: How often are you getting them?  Is it reproducible?  Are you doing something like dropping or truncating thousands of tables in a single transaction?

Comment: @jjanes It's often, especially in the midnight. I'm not doing any thing like drop/truncate table.

Comment: Is there a noticable performance problem (in other words, are end-users complaining)?  This is the type of log message that can often be ignored unless it correlates with concrete problems.  Can you come up with a simple test case to reproduce it?  It will be hard to figure out what is going on without a reproduction case.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. There's no performance problem or complains (the system perf was good at that time). I'm sorry, but I really don't know any test cases. I tried to simulate with (notify/listen) but unsuccessful.

Comment: @jjanes I'm curious about that log. Please, do you know any reason why we have that log ? Thank you.

Comment: You get the message because you turned `log_lock_waits` on.

Comment: @LuanHuynh :  did you find any solution of this problem?

Comment: @Simba: unfortunately, It didn't find a good solution for this problem.